# Minimum MIPS stack frame size

Tags: assembly, mips

Why does the MIPS standard require a minimum stack frame size of 24 bytes? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70746823/frame-stack-size-in-mips) claims that the 24 bytes are split up among the return address, old frame pointer, and four argument registers. Each of these is 4 bytes, and 4 * 6 = 24. However, it seems strange to me that the minimum size assumes the argument registers will be saved to the stack frame. This essentially assumes that (1) all functions have at least four parameters and (2) all functions call another function.

Is this really the entire reasoning behind the minimum size requirement? I can't immediately think of any caching benefit either since 24 is not a power of 2 and has no clear relationship to the cache line size, page size, etc. It seems like mandating such a large minimum stack frame size wastes a lot of memory (potentially 3x the memory you actually need), particularly for recursive algorithms that do not have tail recursion.

Note: I am aware of a [GCC bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009070/why-does-gcc-allocate-more-space-than-necessary-on-the-stack-beyond-whats-need) that causes more memory to be allocated for a stack frame than necessary. However, the 24 byte minimum is stipulated by the MIPS standard, so this is unrelated to the GCC bug.

Comment: Those are for callees; the MIPS ABI has "shadow space" like Windows x64.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180418-00/?p=98545 / [Does the prologue of a function can write outside of its frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66936585) / [Why is the order of arguments on stack is in such order that the first argument would be on the lowest adress, second on second lowest and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56032894)

Comment: IMHO, this shadow argument space is support for the older C language code bases that did not use the `...` syntax for varags functions (circa the '80s & '90s) where variadic argument functions might be declared simply with no parameters, e.g. `extern int printf ();`, or `printf ( char *fmt );` rather than a more proper and modern `extern printf ( char*fmt, ... );`.  I think you'll find that RISC V has removed these requirements for ordinary functions, since varargs functions should be declared as such.